# making windows scheduler run once a minute

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

[image]

So the task is setup to run "every 1 minute(s) from 12:00AM for 1 hour(s) every day, starting 4/15/2013". The last run time is 2:51:15PM and the current time is 3:00PM. So why isn't the task been ran in the last 9 minutes and what do I have to do to make it run every minute if what I did is insufficient?

Thanks!

Comment: How long does the task take to execute?

Comment: Depends on how many files exist in a particular directory. It clears the directory after it's done but the first time I ran it it took like ten minutes. The task still hasn't run, either, since 2:51PM. If it was still running wouldn't it indicate that fact somehow?

Comment: Task Scheduler does not start another instance of the task if the task is already running. Scheduler creates the log, you can check it.

Comment: How do you access the log? <http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783861(v=ws.10).aspx> doesn't seem to apply. There is no Advanced menu and there is no *.txt file in C:\WINDOWS\Tasks. My Scheduled Task thing looks more like <http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm>.